Why Can't I Successfully Allocate Space for a 1D Array Anywhere Besides Main?
I'm working with my professor's code that makes a list of 30 random numbers, and it started throwing errors when I tried to run it. I noticed that when I printed out the array contents within the function that allocates space for it using malloc(), they printed out as expected. But when I try to print out the array contents in another function or main, I get garbage values.
I decided to move the allocation to main which eliminated the issue. However, I wasn't aware that allocating space like this below in another function could cause problems when storing values in the array. (Note: *values is the uninitialized array that gets memory allocated to it within the function. When allocated here, this is the only function that correctly prints out the array):
void create(int *values, int n ) {
    values = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        values[i] = rand()%100;
}

Here is the main function. The print function does not print out the correct array elements. Printing the elements from the main also does not work:
int main() {
    int *nums, mid;
    srand(time(0));
    create(nums, 30);//function where memory is allocated
    print(nums, 30);//function where I try to print array
}

Print function:
void print(int *values, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", values[i]);
    printf("\n");
}


The pointer values is passed (as every parameter in C) by value. This means that what you allocate in create does not update nums in main. you need create to accept a int** for that (and pass &nums from main). Alternatively return an int* from create and assign it into nums.


void create(int *values, int n ) {
    values = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        values[i] = rand()%100;
}


The values argument is a pointer passed by value. Your function re-assigns this to the pointer returned by malloc, but this has no effect on the original pointer.
You need to pass a pointer to a pointer:
void create(int **values, int n ) {
    *values = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        *values[i] = rand()%100;
}

Now main looks like:
int main() {
    int *nums, mid;
    srand(time(0));
    create(&nums, 30);//function where memory is allocated
    print(nums, 30);//function where I try to print array
}

Of course, you also want to check that malloc succeeded before trying to use that memory to avoid undefined behavior.
Alternatively, have create allocate the array dynamically and return a pointer to it. Of course, anytime you use malloc, remember to free that memory.
#define N_NUMS 30

int *create(size_t n) {
    int *values = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    if (!values) return NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        values[i] = rand() % 100;

    return values;
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(0));
    int *nums = create(N_NUMS);

    // Only print if the array was successfully created.
    if (nums)
        print(nums, N_NUMS);

    free(nums);
}


Beware srand(time(0));.  If someone knows when you ran the program, it becomes easy to duplicate the values from rand().  And if the program runs more than once in any single second the sequence of values from rand() will be repeated.

@AndrewHenle While absolutely true, that is not useful information for an introductory CS class dealing with random values suitable for simple video games. If OP were working on something requiring any degree of cryptographic security, rand() and friends would already be off the table.
